# PyQt Classes Multiprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, python-multiprocessing

I want to be able to instantiate a number of QWidget() type classes, each in a separate process. Like Google Chrome does when you open a new tab.

Is this possible in python ?

Comment: I'm only interested on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUI elements (including `QWidget`) can only be created in the main thread.

However, you could put the model and business logic for each tab in a separate thread, and have each communicate with the main thread using `Signals` and `Slots`.  The [Qt documentation for `QThreads`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) provides an example of the *Worker Pattern* for doing this.

This way, if any of the worker processes become hung, it won't effect the responsiveness of your main GUI thread.

```
class MyTab(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
       ...
       self.worker = Worker()
       self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
       self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
       self.worker.resultReady.connect(self.handleResult)
       self.thread.start()

    def callSomeFunction(self):
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.worker, 'someFunction', QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, QtCore.Q_ARG(str, 'arg1'))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def handleResult(self, result):
        ... # do stuff with result


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    resultReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def someFunction(self, arg):
        ...
        self.resultReady.emit({'func': 'someFunction', 'result': True})
```

Comment: This could be useful for me, but unfortunately I can't get it working. It always fails at the invokeMethod call .

Comment: RuntimeError: QMetaObject.invokeMethod() call failed   :(

Comment: You might need to declare the functions as `Slots`.  I've updated the answer.  You could also try calling the function without any arguments and see if that works.

Comment: It works now ! Thank you for your time. I will try to implement this into my app and see if it has any effect on the GUI's fluidity. Cheers ! :D